# Opening a .tar.gz file with a single command

Tags: linux, gzip, tar, gunzip

When I download a .tar.gz file, I open it with two commands, first `gunzip` and then `tar`.

Is it possible to open it with just one command?

Comment: i think this would better fit superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
tar xzf file.tar.gz
```

The letters are:

- x - extract
- z - gunzip the input
- f - Read from a file, not stdin

Comment: This is correct. The only thing that I would add is that z usually only works on gnu tar. The typical UNIX tar won't have this in my experience at least.

Comment: `tar xf file.tar` if you have `file.tar`.

Comment: If you are working with a very large .tgz file, and unzipping it to the same file system will result in an out of disk space error, you can add `--directory /existing/target/directory` where `/existing/target/directory` is on another file system that has sufficient space. This is especially handy if said destination file system can't handle files as large as the particular .tgz file. In this case adding `v` to the options as mentioned in @WiseTechi 's answer (and other answers) can be useful so you know it is actually working as desired.

Answer (score 12):

You can use tar with a "z" argument

```
tar xvfz mytar.tar.gz
```

Comment: what does the 'v' argument do?

Comment: v stands for "verbose" - I like to see what my command is doing

Comment: in fact, for extract `x` mode, you don't have to specify `z` with newer tar -- it is autodetected (GNU tar 1.20+).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have gnu tar it is still possible to open the file in a single step (although technically still two commands) using a pipe

```
zcat file.tar.gz |tar x
```

Answer (score 2):

> The only thing that I would add is
> that z usually only works on gnu tar.
> The typical UNIX tar won't have this
> in my experience at least. – Jon Mar
> 16 at 16:19

The z option works well on my [OS X v10.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard) (Leopard) as well.

When it comes to memorizing, I think it´s easy to think of what you want and not just some letters.

1. If you want to **c**reate an archive, then c will be the first option, else x will be the first option if you want to e**x**tract.
2. If you want to compress/decompress with the g**z**ip/gun**z**ip program, then the next option should be z for zip. (All archives ending with .gz must be unzipped with the z option)
3. The last mandatory option is f for the file.

Then you usually end up with these two commands:

- tar czf file.tar.gz /folder_to_archive/*
- tar xzf file.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

**How do I extract a gz file?**

Use the guzip command as follows:

```
gunzip file.gz
```

*Or*

```
gzip -d file.gz
```

**How do I extract a tar.gz or .tgz file?**

Files with extension tar.gz or .tgz are tar files compressed with gzip. On Unix system extract them with following command:

```
gunzip < file.tar.gz | tar xvf -
gunzip < file.tgz | tar xvf -
```

If you have GNU tar (Linux system) you can use the z option directly:

```
tar xvzf file.tar.gz
tar xvzf file.tgz
```

To read more, see *[Linux / UNIX command to open .gz files](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-compress-expand-gz-files/)*.

Answer (score 1):

Untar Single file from tar File compressed file

To extract a single file called video.mpeg from video.tar use the following command as given below example.

```
# tar -xvf video.tar video.mpeg
```

video.mpeg

Extracting Single file from tar.gz File

Use the following command to extract a single file codefile.xml from websitecode.tar.gz archive file

```
# tar -zxvf websitecode.tar.gz code.xml
```

code.xml

Extracting Single file from tar.bz2 File

Use the command to extract single file file.html from websitecode.tar.bz2

```
# tar -jxvfwebsitecode.tar.bz2 home/website/file.html
```

/home/website/file.html

Also you can read more about all the tar commands at [This link explains all the useful tar commands available in linux](http://www.pagalparrot.com/useful-tar-commands-example-in-linux-to-setup-server-using-ssh-2/)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, try the [tartool](http://tartool.codeplex.com/) utility.

It's free and the code is open source and uses the SharpZipLib library.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this utility.

Answer (score 0):

*Nowadays* `tar` decompresses automatically if needed. It is enough to write:

```
tar xf file.tar.gz
```

Mnemonic: e**x**tract **f**ile