# Programmatically extract tar.gz in a single step (on Windows with 7-Zip)

Tags: scripting, gzip, archive, tar, 7zip

**Problem:** I would like to be able to extract tar.gz files in a single step. This makes my question *almost*  identical to this one: [Stack Overflow question for tar-gz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651018/opening-a-tar-gz-file-with-a-single-command).

My question is *almost* the same, but not the same, because I would like to do this on windows using 7-Zip command-line (or something similar) inside a bat file or Ruby/Perl/Python script.

**Question:** This seemingly simple task is proving to be more involved than the first appearance would make it out to be. Does anyone have a script that does this already?

Comment: [Related on superuser.com](//superuser.com/q/80019)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
7z e example.tar.gz  && 7z x example.tar
```

Use `&&` to combine two commands in one step. Use the 7-Zip portable (you will need 7z.exe and 7z.dll only).

Comment: This isn't exactly one step.  It's still doing the gzip step first, leaving a potentially very large tar file around.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12321558/5612605 (answere from @senthil ) to have a single handy solution ; )

Answer (score 86):

Old question, but I was struggling with it today so here's my 2c.  The 7zip commandline tool "7z.exe" (I have v9.22 installed) can write to stdout and read from stdin so you can do without the intermediate tar file by using a pipe:

```
7z x "somename.tar.gz" -so | 7z x -aoa -si -ttar -o"somename"
```

Where:

```
x     = Extract with full paths command
-so   = write to stdout switch
-si   = read from stdin switch
-aoa  = Overwrite all existing files without prompt.
-ttar = Treat the stdin byte stream as a TAR file
-o    = output directory
```

See the help file (7-zip.chm) in the install directory for more info on the command line commands and switches.

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359793/programmatically-extract-tar-gz-in-a-single-step-on-windows-with-7zip/14699663#comment42886706_14699663) by [@zespri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284111/zespri) powershell will buffer the input to the second 7z process so can consume a lot of memory if your tar file is large. i.e:

```
& 7z x "somename.tar.gz" -so  | & 7z x -aoa -si -ttar -o"somename"
```

A workaround from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28058958/737471) if you want to do this from powershell is to pass the commands to cmd.exe:

```
& cmd.exe '/C 7z x "somename.tar.gz" -so | 7z x -aoa -si -ttar -o"somename"'
```

Comment: a word of advise: if you running it on windows, and your archive is large do not run this under powershell - it will suck the whole thing into memory instead of streaming. open cmd prompt and run it from there.

Comment: This is awesome.  (Note that when I tried it (v15.12), it created the tar file in the working directory, but deleted it when it was done)

Comment: @Dave That doesn't happen for me in 15.11. Were you running it directly in a cmd prompt or in powershell with the cmd workaround?

Answer (score 13):

Use the [win32 port of tar](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libarchive.htm).

```
tar -xvfz filename.tar.gz
```

Comment: lately you must run bsdtar instead of tar but still a great idea and simpler than using 7zip

Answer (score 8):

Since you asked for 7-zip or something similar, I am providing an alternative tool that was written for your exact use case.

The [tartool utility](https://github.com/senthilrajasek/tartool) is a free and open source tool built using the .NET SharpZipLib library.

Example commmand to extract a `.tar.gz` / `.tgz` - file,

```
C:\>TarTool.exe D:\sample.tar.gz ./
```

Disclaimer : I am the author of this utility.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see 7-Zip is not very good at this. People have been [asking for](//sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/5eb1b8d5)
tarball atomic operation since 2009. As an alternative, you can use the
[Arc program](//github.com/mholt/archiver/releases). Example command:

```
arc unarchive test.tar.gz
```