# How to create multiple ZIP files in a folder based on 4GB size restriction?

Tags: linux, bash, rhel7

I have a directory which contains files and I need to create individual ZIP files of these files based on a 4GB size restriction **without** creating a multipart ZIP archive. Could someone help here how to achieve this?

I knew about passing the `-s` parameter to the ZIP command (`zip -s 4096m zipfile.zip *.xml`) but htis will create a multipart ZIP which I don't need it.

And I need to split the ZIP files based on the 4GB size with incremental ZIP file names like if I do `zip -s 4096 archive.zip *.xml`. It should create ZIP files like `archive.zip`, `archive1.zip` with size of 4GB split etc. in the same directory but not the multipart ZP files like `archive.zip`, `archive.z01` etc..

Comment: You have to give more details: what kind of resulted file to you want? What are the target and the goal.

Comment: With a temporary file, you could add file by file, by using `tar --append -f tarballtest.tar "$file"`, while `[[ $(zstd <tarballtest.tar | LANG=C wc -c) -lt 4000000000 ]]`, or so...

Comment: I need to do split the zip files based on the 4GB size with incremental zip file name like if I do zip -s 4096 archive.zip *.xml should create zip as archive.zip, archive1.zip with size of 4gb split etc in the same directory not the multipart zip like archive.zip, archive.z01 etc.

Comment: Ok it's approx what I've guessed. So yes: You'd better using `tar | zstd`, for quickness and efficience. See my previous comment about kind of `while` loop...

Comment: Insted of adding details in comments, edit your question! Add clearly that the goal is to be able to 1. index your archives files and 2. be able to access directly one archive file without the need of reconscruct whole archive.

Comment: I need only to .zip files not the tar archive

Comment: So you could do something same, by successive tries, but as you have to re-build each zip until size reach limit, this will take a lot of resources and time!!! The more: using `zstd` instead of `gzip` or `zip` will reduce resource consumtion by approcx `7/8`!!

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as follow

- There is a directory with a variable amount of XML files
- Zipping all files via `zip zipfile.zip *.xml` would result into a ZIP file bigger than 4GB
- You don't want or can't use multipart ZIP `zip -s 4096m zipfile.zip *.xml` because of [How to `unzip` a multipart (spanned) ZIP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/)
- You don't want or can't use the `split` command to [split one huge file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031144/) because you would need to [join files after splitting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24630/) also
- You don't want or can't use `tar` either, even if it is possible to [open a `.tar.gz` file with a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651018/) or to [unpack or extract](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145342/) files

but you want to create [ZIP files with size limit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198982/).

The command `zipslit`

> reads a zipfile and splits it into smaller zipfiles.

whereby the parameter

> ```
>   -n size
>          Make zip files no larger than "size" (default = 36000).
> ```

So, to split the ZIP files do a test with

```bash
zip zipfile.zip *.xml
zipsplit -t zipfile.zip
```

Comment: I could see zipsplit has limitation of splitting the 2GB[https://www.computerhope.com/unix/zipsplit.htm] file only in my case it should be 4GB file but I resolved my issue using zipsize counter in loop when its reached it will increment the zip name with seq.